# Android Navigation - Unable to get Saved State Handle from Dialog Destination

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I am trying to pass data from dialog destination to fragment. But it is not getting called If I try the same consecutively. For single try it works fine.

Below is my code that is in my dialog fragment:

```
val navBackStackEntry = findNavController().getBackStackEntry(R.id.fragment_name)
```

onClick of button I am doing this

```
navBackStackEntry.savedStateHandle.set(ConstantUtils.SAVED_DATE, "")
dismiss()
```

In fragment's `onResume` I am observing the data like below:

```
 val savedStateHandle = findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle
savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<String>(ConstantUtils.SAVED_DATE)?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, 
Observer { date ->
               //Code goes here
                savedStateHandle.remove<String>(ConstantUtils.SAVED_DATE)
            })
```

When I click the button from dialog it comes to `onResume` of `fragment`, If I again go to the dialog and click on button it does not return to `onResume` of `fragment`.

Pleas let me know what mistake am I making here.

Comment: do you find some solution for this ?

Comment: @AlexZaraos Yes I did find a way

Comment: how do you resolve this problem? In my case I update to Fragment and FragmentKtx to 1.3.0 in order to use FragmentResultListener but I would like to know how to resolve with savedStateHandle

Comment: @AlexZaraos I have used a flag and I have fixed it. Didnt get any direct way...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass argument to fragment and receive one, you can use setFragmentResult() function can pass and receive bundle between fragments.
This is source link for more study

https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result